# Setting up React Native on Mac

Tags: macos, react-native

I'm trying to install React Native on Mac but I'm not able to get past the first step.

```
npm install -g expo-cli
```

This seems to work but when I run the next step `expo init AwesomeProject` I'm getting this error.

```
-bash: expo: command not found
```

I also do not have a `.npm-global` folder. I'm running npm 6.13.4 on Mac OS X 10.15.2.

Comment: Hopefully the first step passes without any errors..

Comment: Thank you for the comment. It is generating errors. I'm editing my post.

Comment: Ok, I was able to fix those errors and have it installed but I'm still having the same original problem.

Answer (score 2):

This might be a local environment issue.

Your computer should know *where to look* for the commands you're using, it's likely that your mac is not looking for the correct folder.

In order to `expo` command works, you must have `/Users/yourUser/.npm-global/bin` in your `$PATH` commands.

- Open your global bash_profile file `vim ~/.bash_profile`.
- add `export PATH=$PATH:~/.npm-global/bin`.

Save the changes, and right after in your command line:

- `source ~/.bash_profile`

Now you can try the command again!

Important Note: `.bash_profile` will run only on login shells. For non-login shells, you would need to create or edit `.bashrc` with this line above.

Comment: I don't seem to have a .npm-global folder. I just have .npm and .npm-packages folders.